# Raw fuel on plug 2,4,6 in my 08 jeep liberty sport 4x4 with 3.7 litre engine

Tags: troubleshooting, diagnose

This all started after dying at stop sign with no warning, no lights, no smoke, not a mis, nothing but it was unable to start put jump box on it and it crank over a few times. Found out that my starter was burnt up so I replaced it and now I have raw fuel on plugs 2,4,6 and runs like crap.

Comment: If there are individual ignition coils to each spark plug, it's there a blown fuse?